# Is that initial compulsory in a ticket for domestic travel?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, india, domestic-travel

I have booked a ticket from Delhi to Chennai and my full name as per ID is V Vimalkumar but while booking I have entered only Vimalkumar.

Will this create a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Domestic travel is less restrictive as compared to international travel. I've known people whose names were misspelled and had no problem for domestic flights. It highly unlikely that you face issues.

Enjoy your flight.